# Agreement of tenses in indirect speech

Tags: grammar

I'm studying agreement of tenses in indirect speech,

and it says we should change tense in accordance with the tense of the main clause's verb, as in

> Argentina and France **will** both reach the final. --> In 2002, Pele *said* Argentina and France **would** both reach the final
>
> He asked, "**Are** you single?"
>   --> He asked me *if* I **was** single.
>
> I asked, "**Did** you **buy** the book?" --> I asked him *if* he **had bought** the book.

But then, one example sentence in the book is written,

> Mike seemed frustrated because of that(the fact that some stakeholders care only about make more profit, not the environment). He wondered *if* sustainable development **is** even possible in this condition.

I think the verb here, "is", should be "was" as I was taught in the book,

since the verb of the main clause is written in past tense, "wondered". (and thus the verb in indirect clause should follow the tense of the main clause.)

Is there anything I'm missing on?

Comment: So, first, whether I use "is" or "was" here, both are right. second, if the speaker wants to focus on the present, we can use present tense verb in indirect speech. Have I understood right?

Comment: And when is using present tense verb in indirect sentence NOT allowed? For example, if this was on the exam and I had to choose one of them, I don't know the speaker's intention so both could be possible.

Comment: There's a helpful guide at: https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm